# Alignment issue which prevents me to sign up from mobile

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

Last night when i try to have a signup to Stackoverflow (I was helping to signup for new account to my friend). When i pressed on the signup button the alignment was like the given below screen which didn't allow me to type the email or password. 
[image]

I am using Moto G - 2nd Gen and the latest version of Google chrome.

Can it be fixed?

Comment: Why? The Google button is right there.